# View controller IOS switch between views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am new at ios programming and I need some help, can't figure out how I am going to switch between two views without firing a button event

I have a splash screen waits for 2 sec then it should go to main view. I don't know how I am going to acquire the main view's reference and navigate to main view!

Any tutorial about switching between views programmatically?

Thanks for your help.
Cheers

Comment: you want to make like when app start it show splash screen and then your home screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with one of Xcodes default projects, and see how they are setup. They should give you a window, with a main view out of the box.

If you add a Default.png image file to your project, it will automatically be used as a splash screen and displayed upon startup. However it will not be visible for 2 seconds, but rather as long as it takes for the application to start.

If you want it to be displayed longer, you will have to add a UIImageView with the same png image to your mainview, then remove this from your mainview after two seconds.

You can use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay to trigger the hiding of the UIImageView after a period of time. However this goes against Apples design guide, as the splash screen only is meant as a ting for the user to look upon before the application launches.

As for adding new views, I recommend using a UINavigationViewController. Using this enables you to navigate back to the main view, and you also get a nice animation as a transition between the views.

Comment: Ok, but I need to add progress bar on the splash screen how am I gonna do that?

Comment: Ok, then you need to use the Default.png for the initial splash screen. The first thing you do when your application delegate fires, is to add a UIImageView with the same picture on top of your main view. Then you add the progressbar component as a another subview to your main view again on top of your splash. Now in order to make the progress bar move while you do other stuff, you need to make sure you do not block the mainthread, because that is needed to change the progress bar values. Look into GCD for multithreading.

Comment: I already have a start view. I need to switch to the second view programmatically.

Comment: Yes, and you do that by adding a subview to your start view. If you want to be able to navigate back to the start view at any point I recommend adding a UINavigationViewController, with the start view as it's root controller, then add the second view with "[yourNavController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]". If you do not want to have navigation or animation transitions, you can simply use "[startView addSubView:secondView]" to show the second view.

Answer (score 1):

For Splash screen you have to name it Default.png and in appDelegate didFinishlaunchingMethod, you have to add view controller to window. the Default.png is automatically reference as a splash screen. try it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between views you use `addSubview`

maybe this tutorial will help ->[Tutorial](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=191002)